# Not able to get the value out of query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am running this below code but it returns an error as: `"undefined index: value"`

```
$two_tier= mysql_query("
    SELECT Count(1)
    FROM(
        SELECT `login_id`
        FROM `data`
        WHERE Year(`start_at`) = Year(Date_sub(Now(), INTERVAL 1 month))
        AND Month(`start_at`) = Month(Date_sub(Now(), INTERVAL 1 month)) 
        AND end_at > Date_add(start_at, INTERVAL 5 minute) 
        GROUP  BY `login_id`
        HAVING Count(`login_id`) > 1
    ) AS Value
");

$two_cnt = mysql_fetch_assoc($two_tier);
echo $two_cnt['value'];
```

I am trying to get the "value". Little help, please.

Comment: The error is quite self explanatory. The returned associative array does not have a key 'value'. DO a `var_dump` to debug.

Comment: @xbonez  value is just a variable i am using to get the result of that query

Comment: @BarbiePylon value is just a variable i am using to get the result of that query

Comment: All you're bringing back is a count.  Your query is wrong.

Comment: No.  You need a variable called "Value" in the outermost select.  Perhaps you should just use the subquery in the WHERE clause, if that is what you want.

Comment: Your outer query is only selecting `count(1)` as its only field. There is `value` field to be retrieved.

Comment: @user1424394: I edited the query in your question.  You had too many `()` and it was confusing to read.  Since you are using `AND`, you don't need to put `()` around each `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @Rocket Thanks man...will keep that in mind from next time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT Count(1) as my_value
FROM   (SELECT `login_id` 
        FROM   `data` 
        WHERE  ( Year(`start_at`) = Year(Date_sub(Now(), INTERVAL 1 month)) 
                 AND Month(`start_at`) = Month(Date_sub(Now(), INTERVAL 1 month) 
                                         ) ) 
               AND ( end_at > Date_add(start_at, INTERVAL 5 minute) ) 
        GROUP  BY `login_id` 
        HAVING Count(`login_id`) > 1) AS Value


$two_cnt = mysql_fetch_assoc($two_tier);
echo $two_cnt['my_value'];
```

you select your FROM as Value, but result of first select isn't in that Value, you need one more AS

Comment: Thanks a lot dude...got it. one question though....you can identify i used a AS value at the end so now if I remove it does it make adifference to the result?

Comment: I believe in MySQL, you'll need the alias for a subquery.

Comment: Yes, when you use a subquery in a FROM, you need the alias.

Comment: oh okay got that....was trying this small thing since 1 hour, going mad literally. Thanks to you guys.

Comment: @Rocket I am getting the answer one value less than what I am supposed to get. When i run the query from phpmyadmin i'm getting the result 20 but when i run it from the browser it gives 19

Comment: @user1424394: Try `COUNT(*)` instead of `COUNT(1)`.

Comment: @Rocket `echo $two_cnt['my_value'];` getting result. But using `echo '<br/>'."value is: $two_cnt['my_value']";` not getting. Y so?

Comment: @user1424394: `echo '<br/>'."value is: {$two_cnt['my_value']}";` or `echo '<br/>'."value is: $two_cnt[my_value]";`

Answer (score 3):

Since the exterior most value in `SELECT` statement is `SELECT Count(1)`, so you are actually fetching `Count(1)` as `Count(1)` instead of `value`. To fetch it as value, you'll need to do it as:

```
SELECT Count(1) AS value ....
```

and then the code will work fine. So, the final statement will be:

```
$two_tier= mysql_query("
    SELECT Count(1) AS value
    FROM(
        SELECT `login_id`
        FROM `data`
        WHERE Year(`start_at`) = Year(Date_sub(Now(), INTERVAL 1 month))
        AND Month(`start_at`) = Month(Date_sub(Now(), INTERVAL 1 month)) 
        AND end_at > Date_add(start_at, INTERVAL 5 minute) 
        GROUP  BY `login_id`
        HAVING Count(`login_id`) > 1
    ) AS Value
");
```

Comment: OP did exactly that, it's a subquery inside the FROM() statement.

Comment: @AlexBelanger Actually, I don't think so. Check the indentation(or order of parenthesis yourself).

Comment: @AlexBelanger, no, OP is aliasing the temp table

Comment: when i changed as above then it gives me this : Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource,

Comment: No OP didn't.  This is the right answer.  (well, part of it, the case thing is still sort of an issue)

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs Which is why I suggested `value` instead of `Value` :)

Comment: Actually, you do need to put `AS Value` after `FROM`.  Every derived table must have its own alias.

Comment: @Nerd-Herd: "The [AS] name clause is mandatory, because every table in a FROM clause must have a name" Docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/from-clause-subqueries.html